# Dropbox service not starting automatically after kernel upgrade

Tags: 12.04, server, services, dropbox

I upgraded a kernel on my 64bit 12.04 server and now the Dropbox service is not launching after the reboot. I can still start it manually by:

```
sudo service dropbox start
```

I was using the instructions found [here](http://ubuntuservergui.com/ubuntu-server-guide/install-dropbox-ubuntu-server)

```
sudo update-rc.d dropbox defaults
```

results are below:

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/dropbox missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/dropbox already exist.
```

Comment: Did you perhaps just disable it under "Startup applications"?

Comment: Where can I check for this? I don't have a GUI(server os)

Comment: I don't know if it's the same on a server, but on a desktop system the startup applications are in `.config/autostart`. There should be a file called dropbox.desktop. Open it with nano and see wheter `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By re-installing Dropbox application problem was fixed.